# zoom to given x y pixels on imageview

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-canvas, zooming

I am developing one application, i am using [this](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java) library. I need to set x and y pixel to image view. I am showing that point on image view. Now the problem is i am getting large images from server. So inorder to see that point lot of scrolling is performed. How can i automatically set zoom to that x and y pixel? Please help me.

```
touchImageView.setScrollX(290);
touchImageView.setScrollY(130);
```

Comment: hey did you get the answer for that question.. i am also struggling on this issue

Comment: no@VivekPratapSingh